# How to re-use jQuery function with different values?

Tags: jquery, function

I have an input field with file type, and beneath it a placeholder image. When I select an image from my file input, the image is shown in my image placeholder. Thats all fine and dandy, but I need to be able to do this multiple times on the same page, and I dont know how to make my function re-usable, becaue the script is one I have found, and I haven't learned JS og jQuery well enough, to know exactly how to do this.

I know from PHP, that if I have a function, I can call it by writing the name of it, and in parenteses input data/variables, which then is used within the function. I'm pretty sure I can do the same thing with jQuery, I just need to figure out how to go about it.

To make it clear, the value I wish to be able to change this way, is the img_placeholder id.

As far as I can tell, the function is already changing one variable inside, which is the input, but do I just add a comma behind input, chose a name, and replace it with the img_placeholder text within the function?

```js
function readURL(input) {
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            
            reader.onload = function (e) {
                $('#img_placeholder').attr('src', e.target.result);
            }
            
            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
    }
    
    $("#img_input").change(function(){
        readURL(this);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="post_img" type="file" id="img_input">
<img id="img_placeholder" src="" alt="" width="770" height="auto">
```

Comment: yes you can do it like... $("#img_input,#id2")

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to have multiple inputs on the same page, each with an image above/below it, I would consider doing something like this:

```
function processInput()
{
    var inputField = $(this);
    var placeholderId = inputField.attr('data-placeholder');

    if (inputField.files && inputField.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) 
        {
            $('#' + placeholderId).attr('src', e.target.result);
        }

        reader.readAsDataURL(inputField.files[0]);
    }   
}

$("#img_input1").change(processInput);
$("#img_input2").change(processInput);
```

Then, your html would look something like this:

```
<input name="post_img1" type="file" id="img_input1" data-image="img_placeholder1">
<img id="img_placeholder1" src="" alt="" width="770" height="auto">

<input name="post_img2" type="file" id="img_input2" data-image="img_placeholder2">
<img id="img_placeholder2" src="" alt="" width="770" height="auto">
```

You could simplify your bindings even further by doing this:

```
$("input[type=file]").change(processInput);
```

But, I'm not sure if this is the end effect you're looking for. But, you can make use of just a single function call this way by associating the input field with the placeholder using additional attributes.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I simply can't get this to work.
I noticed that in your HTML you used the name "data-image", and in the JS you called it "data-placeholder", but changing this didn't make it work either.

I would however like to simplyfy this as much as possible. The goal for me is to be able to dynamically add more input fields with JS, and each of these should be able to show a preview. But first, I need the previews to work, then I guess it's basically just creating a button that appends the new content, and auto-increment it.